# gh-pages --permission denied

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I tried updating my react app on github pages, however I can't run the command "npm run deploy". I cloned my repository, made some changes, pushed them to my main branch. All fine. Then when trying to use "run deploy" with GH pages it gives me a "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.". However, my .ssh key works fine (I was able to push changes to my main branch without any issue).
What am I missing here to make it work?

I tried to authenticate to github with my .ssh key and I have no issues. I have no issues pushing changes to my main branch as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible causes of this issue:

- The repository where you are trying to deploy is not a public repository, it is a private repository and you don't have the necessary permissions to push the changes to the `gh-pages` branch.
- The `gh-pages` branch doesn't exist, If the repository doesn't have any GitHub Pages branch, GitHub will not create one until a GitHub Pages build is pushed to it.
- There is a problem with the `gh-pages` branch, such as it being deleted or having uncommitted changes. This can cause a problem with pushing to the branch.
- Your Git configuration is not set up properly. Make sure that your Git global configuration settings, such as email and username, are set correctly.
- There might be a problem with SSH key. The SSH key that is associated with your GitHub account might have been removed or changed, which would make it impossible for you to push to the repository.
- There might be a problem with your internet connection or a firewall blocking your connection.
- You might have enabled 2FA for your GitHub account, in which case you need to generate a personal access token in order to push to your repository.

You could try the following steps to troubleshoot this issue:

- Try cloning the repository again, and make sure that you are able to access it.
- Make sure that you are able to push to other branches on the repository
- Check if the `gh-pages` branch exists
- Make sure that your Git configuration settings are set up properly.
- Check if your SSH key is still associated with your GitHub account.
- Check your internet connection
- Check your firewall settings

Comment: I checked all of that but still have the same issue.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT. You should delete it because we take plagiarism seriously here.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around I found a solution to my problem.

1. Delete my local repository
2. Clone it using GitHub Desktop
3. Then I was able to run "npm run deploy" without any issues

I'm not sure why it works. I'm assuming there was some issues when cloning from the CLI but I'm not sure about what they are exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have a solution. It involves a manual workaround instead of using `npm deploy`.

1. Generate the production build of your React app in the command line:

   `npm run build`
2. Init a new git repo, add, and commit:

   `git init`

   `git add .`

   `git commit -m "An informative message"`
3. Create a new branch for deployment. This is good practice. Keep your main branch clean:

   `git checkout -b <your-deployment-branch>`
4. cd to your "build" directory that was created in step 1:

   `cd build`
5. Now that you are in the build directory, init another new git repo:

   `git init`
6. Add the remote GitHub repo using the ssh-url:

   `git remote add origin git@github.com:your-git-user-name/your-repo-name.git`
7. Add and commit the changes you have made:

   `git add .`

   `git commit -m "An informative message"`
8. Push the changes you have made to the branch you made at step 3:

   `git push origin <your-deployment-branch>`
9. Almost there! We are done with the command line. Now it is time to take a journey to your GitHub repo settings.
10. Navigate to "Pages" under "Code and automation" on the left-side menu of the webpage.
11. Scroll down to "Branch." Click the dropdown menu that probably says "main" on the left-hand side. Select the deployment branch you made in step 3.
12. Click "Save."

Eureka! Your React app is now deployed on GitHub pages. It will take a minute for it to register under deployments.

Does this address the underlying issue of `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`? No, it does not. I will post a question on Stack Overflow about how to resolve that issue. I will mention the steps that I took to attempt to resolve it. I will also reference the solution I posted here.

I hope this helps people trying to deploy their React app!